# "to delete" vs "to deleted"?

Tags: grammar, tense

> Are you planning to delete this question now?

vs

> Are you planning to deleted this question now?

Which is better or correct?

Comment: This is quite a basic English. *to* marks infinitive, so it's followed by a bare infinitive (plain) form of verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former is correct.

The infinitive 'to delete' should be used as "Planning" denotes future tense, so using the past tense on "deleted" makes no sense.

Saying 'on deleting' would be better though, as it carries the future tense through with it.